# Website showing localhost?

Tags: domain-name-system, localhost

I recently added a alias and virtualhost to apache on my development machine.
Today I stumbled across a website under the domain http://www.circle.nu/.
This domain showed my localhost homepage (It's pretty distinctive...)
Is there any way this was/can be done with a normal tld? My hosts file doesn't mention any website as such as an alias...
I also checked and it is a valid domain (using whois), and even under curl I couldn't find a redirect or such...
Curl also returned my localhost's apache headers... not another server's headers or a redirect.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The hostname www.circle.nu is mapped to IP address 0.0.0.0 in their DNS.  0.0.0.0
is usually interpreted as the "default network", and in your case that's why you're
getting sent to localhost.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's what I was guessing, but I wasn't sure how...
Most people probably would get a page not found error, because they have localhost:80 as nothing typically...

Answer (score 2):

`www.circle.nu` resolves as 0.0.0.0.